# Replacing characters in TeamCity build script / command

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I've created a build job that allows passing in a branch name as a build parameter and then runs the build to produce the output and copy the resulting artifact to another directory on the build server with the original artifact name suffixed with the branch name.

However when I pass in a branch name containing a slash in it (such as `feature/someFeature`) this causes problems since the `%env.Branch%` is substituted as is and makes the `cp` command think it's a directory.

Is there some way to parse this branch name (or any env / system / build parameter) variable in TeamCity and do some processing on it like for e.g. run a `tr '/' '-'` so that the slashes are replaced with hyphen?

TIA

Comment: is it a windows or linux agent? can you use logical branch names to fix it https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches

Comment: This is a OSX agent. And it does not look like the logical branch name would be solution (at least from what I gathered)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom first build step which cleanses the parameter via any available runner, e.g. using a Command Line runner with a custom script like:

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.BRANCH' value='$(echo "%teamcity.build.branch%" | sed 's|/|-|g')']";
```

This uses a [service message](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter) to set a new environment parameter `BRANCH`, which contains the value of `%teamcity.build.branch%` processed through a simple shell `sed` replacement. It can be used as `%env.BRANCH%` in subsequent build steps.